# PHPExcel print a range area

Tags: php, phpexcel

i need to store in a variale the content of a cell area and after print the value.

The code that i use is:

```
$type=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter('C4:E4');
echo $type;
```

but it doesn't work.How can i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `setAutoFilter()` method is for setting an auto-filtering area in a worksheet, and returns the worksheet object (as shown in the API docs); and PHP's echo displays scalar values, not arrays or objects (unless the class has a `__toString()` method, which the worksheet object does not).

If you need to display the contents of a range of cells, consider using the worksheet's `rangeToArray()` method to return a 2-dimensional array of cells, and you can then loop through that displaying the values for each individual cell. Alternatively, there are various other methods shown in the `/Examples` and `/Documentation` to display data from cells.